# Epub read-along, Highlighting is not working

Tags: epub, fixed-layout

My fixed-layout read-along book is validated finally.  I tested it on the Ipad.  Everything looks fine,  The audio is working fine.  However, there is no word highlighting.  I put this code in the CSS file and the content.opf file.

```
.-epub-media-overlay-active {
color: #f09aec;
}
```

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the following line in your content.opf file:

```
<meta property="media:active-class">-epub-media-overlay-active</meta>
```

Further information and examples can be found on the [IDPF's site](http://www.idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-mediaoverlays.html#sec-docs-assoc-style).